# No installers seem to be present and working on your system - letsencypt

Tags: lets-encrypt

```
$ ./certbot-auto
/home/gautam/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt 
No installers seem to be present and working on your system; fix that or try running certbot with the "certonly" command
```

on using "certonly" option:

```
$ ./certbot-auto --apache certonly
Requesting root privileges to run certbot...
  /home/gautam/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt --apache certonly
The apache plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: NoInstallationError()
```

I am unable to find out which installer it is referring to?